# Can't create Postgres procedure from a query

Tags: postgresql

I am coming from a mssql world and moving over to postgres. I am trying to create a new procedure from a query I wrote and it fails on creation. I am using pgAdmin 4 to create the proc and I've tried copy-pasting the query into the "code" tab of the dialog box.

What I'm trying to accomplish is inserting a bunch of rows into a table and outputting the ids from the identity column into a temporary table. I will be using those ids for more work further down the line, but it's failing before it is even usable. The way I did it in MSSQL was I had a table variable and used "output inserted.id" to get those values to insert into the table variable.

From what I understand, I have to create a temp table and use the returning keyword in postgres. The following query works if I run it in a query window

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
(
    temp_id integer
);

WITH ROWS AS
(
INSERT INTO table_a
        (some_name_a) 
    SELECT some_name_b
       FROM table_b
       RETURNING id)
       
INSERT INTO temp_table(temp_id)
SELECT id FROM ROWS;
```

But when I try to create the procedure for that I get an error saying

"ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE" LINE 3: AS $BODY$CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table^"

Here is what the create proc code looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.temp()
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS $BODY$
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
(
    temp_id integer
);

WITH ROWS AS
(
INSERT INTO table_a
        (some_name_a) 
    SELECT some_name_b
       FROM table_b
       RETURNING id)
       
INSERT INTO temp_table(temp_id)
SELECT id FROM ROWS;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) PL/pgSQL needs `BEGIN ... END` blocks. The temp table seems pretty useless also

Comment: the procedure is incomplete.  i will be using the data in the temp table to do other work, say, updating or inserting into table_c...

Comment: also the BEGIN and END stuff wasn't added by the proc creation tool in pgadmin.  putting a BEGIN and END in the code window didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Don't rely on some "creation tool" to write the procedure. Learn the proper syntax, then write the SQL. You have to do that anyway in order to store the creation script in Git (or a similar source control system).

Comment: sheesh, copy-pasting whatever was in the "sql" tab of the creation tool into a fresh window executed just fine.

Comment: as far as learning the proper syntax, that's why i'm here.  there are differences between postgres and ms-sql and that's what i'm struggling with.  thanks for responding though... :)